# После добавления элеменов в БД, элементи отображаются не сразу в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Для отображения нужно выйти и зайти в приложения. 
Раньше уже задавал этот вопрос, сказали поможет `((MainActivity)getActivity()).mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` эта строчка. Но не помогает. Помогите.

Comment: Вам надо сначала обновить выборку из БД, а потом уже говорить адаптеру что данные изменились

Comment: А как обновить выборку ?

Comment: Скорее всего также как и первоначально получить

Comment: Я сделал как первоначально но все ровно не получилось. Наверное что то не так понял. Не могли б вы посмотреть то что я написал ? Я добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Поменял строчки местами, и все работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` - это метод, с помощью которого адаптер сообщает RecyclerView, что ему (RecyclerView) нужно запросить у адаптера свежие данные. Если новые данные не отображаются, то это значит, что их нет в адаптере. Проверьте, что после добавления элементов в БД вы заново(!) выполняете запрос к БД и передаете новый cursor или список элементов адаптеру. `notifyDataSetChanged()` имеет смысл только после этого.